# extbase: how to sort bidirectional relation items

Tags: php, extbase

I have an extbase model "product" and an extbase model "category". The relation is m:n, one product can have multiple categories, one category can have multiple aricles. So far it works kinda good, I am able to get the articles assigned to a category ($category->getArticles()) and get the categories assigned to an article ($article->getCategories())

What I need to do now is sort the articles assigned to a category. When I call $category->getArticles() I want to sort the result alphabetically by article.name. I tried to do this in the articleRepository:

```
public function initializeObject() {
    $this->setDefaultOrderings(array('name' => QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING));
}
```

but that changes nothing. How and where can I achieve this?